# InvalidArgumentError with model.fit in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

Image classification with CNN. When the `model.fit()` is called, it starts to train the model for a while and is interrupted in the middle of execution and returns an error message.

**Error message** as below

```
InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument:  Input size should match (header_size + row_size * abs_height) but they differ by 2
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_4]]
  (1) Invalid argument:  Input size should match (header_size + row_size * abs_height) but they differ by 2
     [[{{node decode_image/DecodeImage}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_8873]

Function call stack:
train_function -> train_function
```

**Update:** My suggestion is to check the metadata of the dataset. It helped to fix my problem.

Comment: A few issues with the code but the main one I notice is that you are loading in the same dir for the train dataset and the test dataset.

Comment: @yudhiesh You mean the train set and validation set? Yes, they are loaded from the same dir using `image_dataset_from_directory()` with different subset. Test set is separated in another folder. Since it's not much related to the problem so I didn't include it.

Comment: Sorry apologizes that is actually correct. I will add an answer with the changes to make.

Comment: @yudhiesh That's ok. I'll try to share the link to access the dataset in a short while.

Comment: @yudhiesh I've updated the question with the link

Comment: you didnt specify exactly how you fixed it? you mentioned check the metadata but what to look for? what did you find?and what exactly did you do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not to specified the parameter `label_mode` . In order to use `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` as the loss function you need to set it to `int`.
If you do not specify it then it is set to `None` as [per the documentation](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#imagedatasetfromdirectory-function).

You need to also specify the parameter `labels` to be the `inferred` based on the structure of the directory that you read the images from.

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels="inferred",
  label_mode="int",
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
  
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels="inferred",
  label_mode="int",
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I just tried to run it but still got back the same error...

Comment: Could you print out the values `img_height, img_width, IMG_SHAPE` and add it to the question?

Comment: It's alrd there. `img_height` and `img_width` are 180 respectively. `IMG_SHAPE` is `(180, 180, 3)`

Comment: I cannot check the images from the dataset as it is too large but I am guessing that the input shapes from the images are not the same as the size you specified when creating the model.

Comment: I guess this may not be the reason coz I alrd specified the input shape `inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(180, 180, 3))`  which is the same as `img_height` and `img_width` when I imported the dataset. And it also doesn't explain why it's working perfectly fine when one of the classes is removed...

Comment: Do I need to unzip the dataset for you? Or anything I can do to help??

Comment: I would suggest writing a script that checks the sizes of all the images and stores them in a set as a tuple of the width, height and color channels. If the set only has a single tuple that matches `[180,180,3]` then the issue is something else.

Comment: I've updated the code above. Do you have any idea what issue it'd be?

Comment: Could you try changing `label_mode` to be `categorical` and then changing the loss function to be `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy`. Just to see if the issue is stemming from using `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`.

Comment: I just tried it. Still got the same error. I doubt that it's something to do with the image dataset but I've no idea what would be the problem...

Comment: I fixed the problem. Will make an update soon. Anyway thank you for trying to help me.

Comment: @Sunnday what metadata to check? Can you explain it little bit? I am also getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this error when I tried *adding new photos from another camera* to my training dataset.

After reading the comments and the fuss about "metadata", I thought of actually checking the metadata of every photo in the dataset.

In my case, **I had to make sure that the metadata of my photos are consistent, with no extra or fewer fields**.

Normally, I BulkResize (that online tool) my images before training, and it seems that I forgot to resize the new images. This online tool seems to overwrite the images' metadata, thus making every resized photo's metadata uniform.

After making sure that the metadata across all photos is **consistent**, the error went away.

PS: this is only in my case. But this is a sign that you can start with your metadata. I just have the following:

- Dimensions
- Color Profile
- Color Space

Hope you all find this. Happy training!

Answer (score 0):

I have just answered a very similar question in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69607117/tensorflow-invalid-argument-input-size-should-match-but-they-differ-by-2/73004159#73004159). In fact, the underlying issue might be exactly the same. It contains an elaborate explanation of what is going on at least in my case. Long story short, one possible reason that I proved to be correct is **corrupted JPEG files**.